# How to find the size of a NSString?

Tags: ios, string-formatting, font-size

When writing an app, sometimes comes across situations where we need to adjust the position and size of a label based on the size of the text. And that size could be different based on a particular font we are using,so what we will do that problem?

Comment: so what is your problem then?

Answer (score 3):

```
-(CGRect)estimateTextSize:(UILabel *)lblObject
{
   CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(lblObject.frame.size.width,9999);

   CGSize expectedLabelSize = [lblObject.text sizeWithFont:lblObject.font
                                       constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                           lineBreakMode:lblObject.lineBreakMode];
   CGRect newFrame = lblObject.frame;
   newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
   lblObject.frame = newFrame;
   return lblObject.frame;
}
```

i hope, this will help you...

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Adjust the label to `Size to Fit Content` (if you have the label in Interface Builder), then set it's constraints.